# Installing Oracle 11g on CentOS via Yum

Tags: yum, centos7, terminal, oracle-11g

I'm trying to set up a CentOS 7 VM to host an Oracle 11gR2 database. There is no desktop/x window system software, but I did try installing the 11gR2 zips with

`./runInstaller -silent -noconfig -responseFile <responseFile>.rsp`

but this just returned a java stack trace pointing to swing libraries erroring (no surprise - the reason I'm using -responseFile and -silent is because I can't run a UI. Don't know why swing libraries are even being invoked.)

So I've moved on to using the oracle public yum repository:

`yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall`

But this gives the following output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: www.mirrorservice.org
 * extras: mirrors.melbourne.co.uk
 * updates: mirrors.melbourne.co.uk
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall.x86_64 0:1.0-12.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-utils for package: oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-12.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-uek for package: oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-12.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: compat-libcap1 for package: oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-12.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ksh for package: oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-12.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio-devel for package: oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-12.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-xauth for package: oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-12.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: compat-libstdc++-33 for package: oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-12.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libcap1.x86_64 0:1.10-7.el7 will be installed
---> Package compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64 0:3.2.3-72.el7 will be installed
---> Package kernel-uek.x86_64 0:2.6.39-400.277.1.el6uek will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-uek-firmware = 2.6.39-400.277.1.el6uek for package: kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.277.1.el6uek.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ql23xx-firmware for package: kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.277.1.el6uek.x86_64
Package ql23xx-firmware-3.03.27-3.1.el6.noarch is obsoleted by linux-firmware-20150904-43.git6ebf5d5.el7.noarch which is already installed
---> Package ksh.x86_64 0:20120801-28.el6_7.3 will be installed
---> Package libaio-devel.x86_64 0:0.3.109-13.el7 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-utils.x86_64 0:7.5-13.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libdmx.so.1()(64bit) for package: xorg-x11-utils-7.5-13.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXxf86misc.so.1()(64bit) for package: xorg-x11-utils-7.5-13.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXxf86dga.so.1()(64bit) for package: xorg-x11-utils-7.5-13.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXv.so.1()(64bit) for package: xorg-x11-utils-7.5-13.1.el7.x86_64
---> Package xorg-x11-xauth.x86_64 1:1.0.9-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXmuu.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.9-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel-uek.x86_64 0:2.6.39-400.277.1.el6uek will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ql23xx-firmware for package: kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.277.1.el6uek.x86_64
Package ql23xx-firmware-3.03.27-3.1.el6.noarch is obsoleted by linux-firmware-20150904-43.git6ebf5d5.el7.noarch which is already installed
---> Package kernel-uek-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.39-400.277.1.el6uek will be installed
---> Package libXmu.x86_64 0:1.1.2-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXv.x86_64 0:1.0.10-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXxf86dga.x86_64 0:1.1.4-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXxf86misc.x86_64 0:1.0.3-7.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libdmx.x86_64 0:1.1.3-3.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.277.1.el6uek.x86_64 (ol6_UEK_latest)
           Requires: ql23xx-firmware
           Available: ql23xx-firmware-3.03.27-3.1.el6.noarch (ol6_latest)
               ql23xx-firmware = 3.03.27-3.1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Neither of the two suggestions at the end solve the issue, and (as suggested by the above) attempting to `yum install ql23xx-firmware.noarch` told me I had a better version already installed and refused the install.

So, what is the accepted procedure for installing an Oracle 11g database on a Centos 7 VM with no desktop? Should I try to remove `ql23xx-firmware-3.03.27-3.1.el6.noarch` and then install the obsoleted `ql23xx-firmware`?

Comment: That's Oracle's kernel. You probably will have to ask their support how to use it, and they may tell you to use Oracle Linux.

Comment: @JohnMahowald And so they did: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3907004

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install software built for EL6 on EL7. This isn't going to work. Obtain the correct packages or the correct distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I could make @JohnMahowald's comment the answer I would. The issue is caused by kernel expectations that are not met in CentOS 7. Initially I wanted the SUT and its DB to be on the same VM, to make it simpler to deploy to a desktop development environment. However, I have decided to move to Oracle Linux for the DB, and a separate CentOS VM for the SUT.